# Storing an ISBN in an OracleDB gives precision error?

Tags: oracle, types, oracle11g, precision

**Why am I getting a precision error?**

```sql
INSERT INTO ISBN_LIST (ISBN) VALUES (9780261102354);
```

Given the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ISBN_LIST ( 
    ISBN NUMBER (20,20)  NOT NULL -- NUMBER(13) also didn't work
);
ALTER TABLE ISBN_LIST
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ISBN_LIST PRIMARY KEY ( ISBN );
```

[bonus points if you recognise the ISBN!]

Comment: Hey, we all have google, mate :)

Comment: On the other hand, are you sure you want to store it as a number and not as a string? It may begin with 0, so you will need extra verification of number's length after fetching from dbase to present it correctly...

Comment: Some numeric strings should be stored and treated as strings rather than numbers.

Comment: Indeed, ISBN is *not* a number, it is a string of numeric digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting a precision error for number(20, 20) is because you are creating a number with precision 20 and scale 20, which means numbers:

between 0.00000000000000000000 and 0.99999999999999999999.

According to this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe803/1), `number(13)` works (maybe you need to specify `number(13, 0)` to ensure the right scale, though I would agree with @xavier that a `varchar2(13 char)` is probably a better choice of datatype.

Comment: Thanks, it needed the `,0` for some reason :\